# UIKit Support using Apportable

Tags: apportable

I have an iOS app that I would like to run on an Android as well. It isn't a game, and makes use of UIKit and storyboards. I have tried to port using apportable, but it is difficult to understand what is, and isn't, supported. I am using the developer's preview version.  Someone from apportable posted that the latest updates to the developers preview could convert the UICatalog "out of the box". I don't find that to be true. So this may be my problem, but I am looking for a route to success.

Does anyone willing to share the steps to port the latest version of UICatalog to an Andriod device using apportable?

Answer (score 0):

if you sign up for the SDK, there's a "developer_preview" version that we have available. this contains our new UIKit. You should be able to *almost* build UICatalog from that.

Comment: As indicated in my question, I am using developer_preview.  And I agree, I have almost built it from that.  My question is regarding what has to be done to get from almost built, to built.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven’t gotten very far with my exploration, King of Dragon Pass is a pure UIKit game, and I have gotten it to compile and run with 1.1.13. (It will take a bunch of work to get it to run ***well***, but it does handle a UIKit app.)